# How can I generate entities with IntelliJ without having a session factory?

Tags: java, hibernate, intellij-idea, dropwizard

I am using our internal libraries for generating a session factory. This means I don't have an `xml` file with Hibernate configuration; information like that are read from a configuration file in the container that my application is deployed in. I also don't create a new instance of `SessionFactory` anywhere in my code; I add a bundle that does that for me.

However, when I try to generate entities with IntelliJ, I get an error saying:

`JPA annotation mappings require at least one Session Factory`

Considering that I don't have a configuration file, and I don't construct the `SessionFactory` myself, is there a way to generate annotations?

Answer (score 10):

You can generate entities using Database connection.

1. Go View->Tool Windows->Database click <kbd>+</kbd> to add new Data Source.
2. Go to "Project structure" (<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd>)
3. In "Project settings" select "Modules"
4. Press <kbd>+</kbd> and add the JPA/Hibernate facet in your module.
5. Go View->Tool Windows->Persistance, RB->Genrate Persisting Mapping->By Database Schema. And choose data source and package where generate.

Comment: Important step here is to add the `JPA` module! After that, no `SessionFactory` setup is required anymore.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using spring data JPA and had a similar problem. To work around it, I created a temporary class as below and let IntelliJ create a hibernate.cfg.xml (hit the green + next to "Add to Session Factory"), both of which I deleted once I'd run the mapping. A bit of an annoying workaround, but much quicker than mapping everything manually. Hope this helps.

```
@Component
public class IMADEANENTITYMANAGEROK/*!?!?!*/ {
    @Autowired
    HibernateJpaSessionFactoryBean hibernateJpaSessionFactoryBean;
    SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    public IMADEANENTITYMANAGEROK()
    {
        sessionFactory = hibernateJpaSessionFactoryBean.getObject();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For Spring Data JPA, add the hibernate.cfg.xml under /resources.

E.g. for postgresql:

```
<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
    <property name="connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/db_name</property> 
    <property name="connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property> 
    <property name="connection.password"></property> 
    <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</property> 
    <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property> 
    <property name="show_sql">true</property> 
    <property name="format_sql">true</property>
</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Set your own db url, username, password. Click browse right of "Add to Session Factory" to point to above hibernate.cfg.xml. Then the POJOs will be generated without error "JPA annotation mappings require at least one Session Factory".

After the generation, delete or rename the file hibernate.cfg.xml to hibernate.cfg.xml.bak incase you use it again.

Comment: worked for me, just had to remove the "connection.driver_class" and "dialect" properties